# Property on model attribute set in one controller method is not available in another controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

Following contains the code inside my controller class , i am using the method public String getRegistrationForm(Map model) to return a jsp-page with a spring form on it , in this method i am setting userTab.setIsMfaEnabled(new Boolean(true)) ,  upon submitting the form the method :
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserTab user , BindingResult results , Map model)
is invoked as the handler method , but in this method the property 'isMfaEnabled' of user attribute set in the previous method is null and the line:System.out.println("user.getIsMfaEnabled() is nul"); is printing in the logs . Kindly tell me what is wrong here .

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterUserController {   
    @Autowired
    RegisterUserService registerUserService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registeruser.action" , method =     RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserTab user , BindingResult results , Map<String,Object> model){
        System.out.println("executing regsiterUser ");
        if(user == null)
           System.out.println(", user is null");
        if(results == null)
           System.out.println("results is null");

        UserTabValiator userTabValidator = new UserTabValiator();
        if(user.getIsMfaEnabled() == null)
            System.out.println("user.getIsMfaEnabled() is nul");
        userTabValidator.validate(user, results);
        if(results.hasErrors()){
           return "registeruser";
        }
        try {
            boolean val = registerUserService.isExistingUsername(user.getLoginName());
            if(val){
                System.out.println("username already exists");
                model.put("message", "username already exists");
                return "registeruser";
            }
           if(!val){
               model.put("username", user.getLoginName());
               model.put("message", "registration success ... ");
               return "registrationsuccess";
           }            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception thrown");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "errorpage";
        }
       return "errorpage";
 }


   @RequestMapping(value="/registeruser.view", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getRegistrationForm(Map<String,Object> model){
       System.out.println("executing getRegistrationForm");
       if(registerUserService == null)
       System.out.println("register user service is null");
       try{
         ArrayList<MfaQuestion> allMfaQuestions = (ArrayList<MfaQuestion>) registerUserService.getAllMfaQuestions();
        UserTab userTab =  new UserTab();
        userTab.setIsMfaEnabled(true);
        model.put("user", userTab);
        model.put("message", "register new user");
        model.put("allMfaQuestions", allMfaQuestions);
        return "registeruser";
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           model.put("user", new UserTab());            
           model.put("message", "unable to get MFA questions");
           return "registeruser";
       }
    }   
}
```

UserTab Model Class :
            package com.persistance.beans;

```
        import java.util.Date;

        public class UserTab {

            private Integer userTabID;
            private String loginName;
            private String password;
            private Date created;
            private Date lastUpdated;
            private Date lastLoginAttempt;
            private Boolean isAccountLocked;
            private Integer loginFailsNumber;
            private Boolean isMfaEnabled;
            private UserMfaMap userMfaMap;

            public String toString(){
                String str ="";
                System.out.println("[userTabID , loginName ,  password");
                return str;

            }

            public UserMfaMap getUserMfaMap() {
                return userMfaMap;
            }

            public void setUserMfaMap(UserMfaMap userMfaMap) {
                this.userMfaMap = userMfaMap;
            }

            public UserTab() {
                super();
            }


            public String getLoginName() {
                return loginName;
            }
            public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
                this.loginName = loginName;
            }
            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
            }
            public Date getCreated() {
                return created;
            }
            public void setCreated(Date created) {
                this.created = created;
            }


            public Date getLastUpdated() {
                return this.lastUpdated;
            }
            public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
                this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
            }
            public Date getLastLoginAttempt() {
                return lastLoginAttempt;
            }
            public void setLastLoginAttempt(Date lastLoginAttempt) {
                this.lastLoginAttempt = lastLoginAttempt;
            }
            public Boolean getIsAccountLocked() {
                return isAccountLocked;
            }
            public void setIsAccountLocked(Boolean isAccountLocked) {
                this.isAccountLocked = isAccountLocked;
            }
            public Integer getLoginFailsNumber() {
                return loginFailsNumber;
            }
            public void setLoginFailsNumber(Integer loginFailsNumber) {
                this.loginFailsNumber = loginFailsNumber;
            }
            public Boolean getIsMfaEnabled() {
                return isMfaEnabled;
            }
            public void setIsMfaEnabled(Boolean isMfaEnabled) {
                this.isMfaEnabled = isMfaEnabled;
            }

            public Integer getUserTabID() {
                return userTabID;
            }

            public void setUserTabID(Integer userTabID) {
                this.userTabID = userTabID;
            }

        }
```

RegisterUser JSP page :

```
            <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/registeruser.action" commandName ="user">
           <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="loginName">UserName</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="loginName" /></td>
                <form:errors path="loginName" cssClass="error"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Password</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
                <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
            </tr>

            <div id="question1" class="questionblock">
            <tr>
                <form:select path="userMfaMap.question1" > 
                <c:forEach items="${allMfaQuestions}" var="mfaQuestion">
                    <form:option  value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestionId}">
                      <c:out value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestion}" />        
                   </form:option>                     
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userMfaMap.answer1">Answer:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userMfaMap.answer1" /></td>
                <form:errors path="userMfaMap.answer1" cssClass="error"/>
            </tr>
            </div>
            <div id="question2" class="questionblock">   
            <tr>
                <form:select path="userMfaMap.question2">
                <c:forEach items="${allMfaQuestions}" var="mfaQuestion">
                    <form:option  value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestionId}">
                      <c:out value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestion}" />        
                   </form:option>                     
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userMfaMap.answer2">Answer:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userMfaMap.answer2" /></td>
                <form:errors path="userMfaMap.answer2" cssClass="error"/>
            </tr>
            </div>
            <div id="question3" class="questionblock">
            <tr>
               <form:select path="userMfaMap.question3">
                <c:forEach items="${allMfaQuestions}" var="mfaQuestion">
                    <form:option  value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestionId}">
                      <c:out value="${mfaQuestion.mfaQuestion}" />        
                   </form:option>                     
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userMfaMap.answer3">Answer:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userMfaMap.answer3" /></td>
                <form:errors path="userMfaMap.answer3" cssClass="error"/>
            </tr>
            </div>

            <tr>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
        </form:form>
```

Comment: hi, could u pls post the jsp form code, and also the UserTab model object

Comment: I have attached the JSP code and the model object class definition as you have asked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code in the JSP form to bind the value of isMfaEnabled

```
 <form:input path="isMfaEnabled" />
```

Comment: it is working thanks , i used : <form:hidden path="isMfaEnabled" /> , is there some other instead since using a hidden form parameter is vulnerable thing to do as it can be tampered with on the client side.

Comment: well, there is one other way - li'l deviation from this. you could set that attribute - in session scope. So add, isMfaEnabled as a seperate attribute in session scope and in the registerUser method get that value from session scope.